Installing Ubuntu, black screen and fan noise
I'm trying to install Ubuntu but running into a problem where when I boot up my computer with the USB with ubuntu on it, it will go into a screen that says Ubuntu and shows a loading icon, then it will go black and my computer fan will start power cycling over and over until I shut off the power. Does anyone have any ideas what is going on?

What brand/model system? What video card/chip? If nViida are you using Safe Boot? If older system, Ubuntu may be too much as now really for newer systems. I could not install Ubuntu on old 2006 laptop with only 1.5GB of RAM, but Kubuntu did work from external SSD.

It's a gigabyte motherboard and an r9 390 graphics card running windows 10.

You've provided no Ubuntu details; is this a Ubuntu Core you're trying to install? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop?  What release of that product, and is it the correct architecture? and if a product/release that has ISO/installer choice; which are you trying to use? How did you write the ISO?  (appropriate method? esp. if release >20.04 using updated software).

Does this answer your question? Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot
